# How to show that (x+y)/(1+xy) is increasing

Tags: derivatives

I:]-1;1[
$$U(x) \in I$$ and $$y \in I
$$
$$\{U:x\to {x+y\over 1+xy}\}$$
How to demonstrate that, U(x) is a non-decreasing function on I ??
I have to dress his variation table (I don't Know how to say in English)
And finally I have to write u(I)

Comment: increasing in $x$ or $y$?

Comment: Sorry for my bad english : a nondecreasing function

Comment: please, could you say in another way what you mean by "I have to dress his variation table". Also consider using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) next time.

Comment: nondecreasing in which variable?

Comment: do you mean in $x$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**: Ignoring the pole at $xy=1$, note that $$\frac{d}{dx} \frac{x+y}{1+xy} = \frac{1-y^2}{(1+xy)^2}$$ and hence the function is increasing in $x$ whenever the right hand side of the above is strictly positive. Since $(1+xy)^2 \geq 0$, what can you conclude?

Comment: If it's > 0 it's nondecreasing !

Comment: It's means that 1-y^2>0 so -sqrt1<y<sqrt1

Comment: So it always > 0 when y \in I so it si increasing

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood your meaning. You are right.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that this answers your question. As I understand, you need to prove u(x) is nondecreasing.
For any $y \in (-1,1)$. Compute
$$ u'(x) = \dfrac{1-y^{2}}{(1+xy)^{2}} > 0 \ \forall y \in (-1,1) $$
which proved that u(x) is nondecreasing.
Your "variation table" would looks like
\begin{array}{c|c c c}
 x & -1 & & 1 \\
\hline
 u'(x) & & + & \\
 u(x) & u(-1) = -1 & \nearrow & u(1) = 1
\end{array}
That is, $u(I) = u \left( (-1,1) \right) = (-1,1)$.

Comment: Thank you and how do we say variation table in  english ?

Comment: I guess variation table of a function is a correct one. I do not use it frequently. All the best :)

Comment: How do you have 1-y^2 because I have 1-x-y-y^2/(...)

Comment: Actually, it was: $(x+y)'(1+xy) - (x+y)(1+xy)' = 1 + xy - y(x+y) = 1 +xy - xy - y^{2} = 1 - y^2$.

Comment: I Know where is my mistake thanks !

Answer (score 0):

If it's increasing as a function of $x$, you can use this simple result on *homographic functions*:

> Let $f\colon x\longmapsto f(x)=\dfrac{ax+b}{cx+d}$ $\,(ad-bc\ne 0)$ be a homographic function.
>
> Then $f$ is
> $\;\begin{cases}\text{increasing}&\text{ if } ad-bc>0, \\[1ex] \text{decreasing}& \text{ if }ad-bc<0.\end{cases}$

Indeed we can rewrite the function as
$$f(c)=\frac{\cfrac{a(cx+d)}{c}+b-\cfrac{ad}c}{cx+d}=\frac ac -\frac{ad-bc}{c^2x+cd}, $$
and note that the second fraction is the product of the constant factor $ad-bc$ by the increasing function $\;-\dfrac{1}{c^2x+cd}$.

- In the present case, $\;ad-bc=1-y^2>0\iff-1<y<1. $